# Result of Inclusion-cells in the I-cell disease

Tags: disease, genetics, enzyme, genetic-predisposition, cells

What happens to the cells once the body doesn't have the lysosomal enzymes to degrade lipids and such. Inclusion bodies appear, but how do they provoke so many symptoms like hepatomegaly motoric delay and finally death?